# UIImagePicker in landscape mode - How to rotate UIAlertViews?

Tags: ios, xcode

In iOS6, How do i rotate UIAlertViews on top of a UIImagePicker when the device is in landscape mode? They are only loading up in portrait, but the app is landscape only. I had to manually rotate a custom cameraOverlayView (UIView), but i don't know how to do this with alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the UIImagePickerController supports only portrait mode:

**From Apple Documentation**
*The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.*

So, when the picker is open, the device orientation is reported as portrait, and the UIAlertView are showed in portrait mode.
Sure, using some "hack" you could rotate the UIAlertView, but the app will probably be rejected during the review.

The only "legal" way is to create your own image picker

Comment: Exactly my problem with the UIImagePicker - What hack would that be? This app will not go through the Apple store.

Comment: I searched and tried something and I correct myself: I was not able to do this on iOS 6 even using some tricks (method swizzle) to force the orientation to be always landscape. My source from Apple says it's no more possible on iOS 6 without massive work

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, You need to subclass the `UIImagePicker` class.

```
@interface yourImagePicker :UIImagePicker 
{
}
@end
```

and you need to implement the `shouldAutoRotate` method in the implementation and return only landscape mode

```
@implementation yourImagePicker 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
@end
```

And you need to create `yourImagePicker` instance instead of `UIImagePicker`

Comment: if i already have a @interface statement in my viewcontroller's .h file, how do i make another? Also i already have a implementation in my .m file. Beginner here.

Comment: you need to create a new file with the name of `yourImagePicker` or you can easily write the above code in your viewcontroller.m file (write it before `@implementation` statement)

Comment: Ok that's in there, one more question. Do i place two 'interface' statements in the .h file?

Comment: you can place two interface in one .h file, I'll suggest to put the second interface in .m file

Comment: I guess i'm too much of a beginner to figure this out, i've got the implementation in there, but to put the interface, i keep getting "undeclared identifier 'MyImagePIckerController"

Comment: Ok i did place the interface statement in the .h file, the build succeeded, but the alert views are still not rotated correctly. sorry.

Comment: @Midhun MP, not sure if this work on iOS 5 (even being "illegal" for Apple), but sure it won't work on iOS 6. On iOS 6 private classes like UIImagePickerController are executed "privately" (not sure if in a protected memory space or sandboxed). Subclassing won't work (no errors from compiler, but unexpected behavior), and even using tricks (like memory swizzle) you won't be able to do it. My source is an Apple employee :)